# How to order sqlite operations

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I'm facing some issues working with sqlite in Python.  I have two joined tables, table1 and table2, joined on 'id'.  The following series of booleans occur within my WHERE clause:

```
...WHERE (table2.word IN ('grapes', 'cherries') GROUP BY
table1.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) AND table1.taste = 'sour';
```

To be more specific, I'm trying to get all the occurrences in table2 that have both 'grapes' and 'cherries' as words, but without having to join table2 twice with different names.  This is why I'm using IN, and then using GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 to isolate the cases where the number of occurrence is exactly equal to the number of fruits I want to match.

However, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: near "group": syntax error
```

I've isolated the problem to the way my parenthesis is working in the first boolean, and have been trying for hours to find out why.  When I take out the second boolean "AND table2.taste = 'sour'", the entire query works just fine.  Should I be shifting GROUP BY and HAVING someplace else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your query should probably be this:

```
WHERE
    table1.word IN ('grapes', 'cherries') AND
    table2.taste = 'sour'
GROUP BY
    table1.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT table1.word) = 2;
```

`WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`, which in turn comes before `HAVING`.  There is a reason for this order, which is that the database usually evaluates each of these clauses in the order in which you see them.

Comment: Thanks! If I happen to have two instances of IN () usage, how can I be sure that the GROUP BY and HAVING don't end up affecting both INs?  That is, I need an occurrence of table1.attribute IN (something1, something2) to be considering either something1 or something2, but the occurrence of table1.word IN ('grapes','cherries') to have both grapes and cherries

Comment: @ilee Check my updated `HAVING` clause.  Assert that the distinct count of table1 words is 2, after restricting to only records with `grapes` and `cherries` in the `WHERE` clause.